# Why was my comment deleted suggesting an improvement to script for listing cron jobs?

Tags: discussion, comments, suggested-edits

My comment on [How do I list all cron jobs for all users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users/18451896#18451896) was deleted by [Andrew Barber ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber)  with no explanation as to why.   I looked at Andrew's activity log and there is no entry that I can find for this deletion.  I would appreciate some feedback to explain why my comment/suggestion was deleted.

Comment: Because it was a comment, posted as an answer (yes, you need 50 rep before you can post comments everywhere, but that's how the sites work.) - the more you participate, the more you _can_ participate.

Comment: Now, why did Andrew go to it? Two people flagged the comment as "not an answer" and rightfully so. Andrew, in his capacity as moderator, acted on these flags.

Comment: Now, how to get 50 rep? Ask a few good question, or better - give a couple of good answers. You can also suggest edits to existing posts to improve them (many posts have bad grammar, spelling and formatting) - every approved edit gains you 2 rep.

Comment: Oded and Linuxios have the reasons down perfectly here. Nothing more I can add. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You posted an answer, not a comment. Answers are only for answering the question. Unlike a forum post, they don't also serve for commentary on other answers. That is solved by Stack Exchange's comment feature, which you will get access to when you get 50 reputation.